# Is there a way to convert Wolfram Language expression to string?

Tags: cells

Is there a way to convert a Wolfram Language expression / code into a string expression? For example,

Convert the following including its indentations (very important),

```
If[Length[$ScriptCommandLine]==1,
    Print["No expressions were given to square."],

    args = Rest[$ScriptCommandLine];
 squares = Quiet @ Map[Replace[ToExpression[#], {$Failed:>ToString[#,InputForm]^2, x_ :> x^2}]&, args];
    MapThread[Print["The square of ", #1, " is ", #2, "."]&, {args, squares}]
]
```

into

```
"If[Length[$ScriptCommandLine]==1,
    Print[\"No expressions were given to square.\"],

    args = Rest[$ScriptCommandLine];
 squares = Quiet @ Map[Replace[ToExpression[#], {$Failed:>ToString[#,InputForm]^2, x_ :> x^2}]&, args];
    MapThread[Print[\"The square of \", #1, \" is \", #2, \".\"]&, {args, squares}]
]".
```

I am looking for a builtin function or a function `f` that can be written to work like

`f[...code...]`→ `...string version of code...`.

I am trying to do this programmatically and probably will require going into the `Cell` expression.

Comment: `ToString` does this.

Comment: Something like this? `StringReplace[ToString[Defer[2 + 2]], "Defer[" ~~ x___ ~~ "]" :> x]`

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? What will you do with the string? Why is indentation important? The indentations are **not** part of the underlying Mathematica expression. You refer to `Cell` expression, but this only exists in the FrontEnd. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Right click on the cell, `Copy As` -> `Plain Text`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In the Front End

I assume you have this typed in a `Cell` in the front-end. That's the only case in which preserving indentation makes sense at the parse step. If that's the case you need simply to get the `Cell` expression and pass it to:

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[ExportPacket[cellExpr, "InputText"]][[1]]
```

If you have the `CellObject` and need the `Cell` expression you do that via [`NotebookRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookRead.html).

If you need the `CellObject` you'll probably find that easiest via [`NextCell`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NextCell.html) and [`PreviousCell`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PreviousCell.html)

#### Regenerating Indentation

If you *don't* have this in the FE and you'd like to regenerate indentation you can do that as I discuss [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174724/38205)

Comment: Thank it works but it seems to be adding extra spaces and newlines where they were not in the original input cell.

Comment: This is the output it produced for me. Its not a big deal I can clean it up with some regex but if it can literally get the input without any modification that would be ideal.
`"If[Length[$ScriptCommandLine] == 1,\r\n \tPrint[\"No expressions were given to square.\"],\r\n \t\r\n \targs = Rest[$ScriptCommandLine];\r\n \tsquares = \r\n  Quiet @ \
Map[\r\n    Replace[ToExpression[#], {$Failed :> ToString[#, InputForm]^2, \r\n       x_ :> x^2}] &, args];\r\n \tMapThread[\r\n  Print[\"The square of \", #1, \" is \", #2, \
\".\"] &, {args, squares}]\r\n ]"`

Comment: Compare this with the output I am expecting.
`"If[Length[$ScriptCommandLine]==1,\n\tPrint[\"No expressions were given to square.\"],\n\t\n\targs = Rest[$ScriptCommandLine];\n\tsquares = Quiet @ \
Map[Replace[ToExpression[#], {$Failed:>ToString[#,InputForm]^2, x_ :> x^2}]&, args];\n\tMapThread[Print[\"The square of \", #1, \" is \", #2, \".\"]&, {args, squares}]\n]"`

Comment: Does `ExportPacket` have some options other than `"InputText"` that can get the input text without any interpretation or modification? These functions don't seem to be documented.

Comment: @user13892 the issue is the `PageWidth` setting. Try stuff with that.